# Ionic Angular - Firebase offline cache returns data one out of two times

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, offline

**Description of the initial situation:**

I have enabled data persistence on Firestore by following the documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline
It works, when I make an offline write request my listener receives the information and I can display it locally.
When I get back to the connection the data are well synchronized.

**Description of the problem:**

- I open the application on android and go offline.
- I make an offline modification to firestore DB.
- I kill my application.
- I reconnect, still offline.
- I try to read the data from the cache.

  - One time out of two : I get the data, it works perfectly.
  - The other time : The cache is like empty and doesn't return any data.

When I say one out of two times, it means that when I kill the app and don't get the data, if I kill it again and open it, I get the data again (without being in online mode). If I do it again, I lose them. (And this boucle is infinite)

The request to get the data is the same each time.

PS : On PWA version, it work every time

**Question:**
How do I get the data from the cache every time? Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution:

I used AngularFire to enable persistence this way (in`app.module.ts`):

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        ...
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
        AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence({synchronizeTabs: true}),
        ...
    providers: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

The option (synchronizeTabs) must be enabled. My guess is that the application was not fully killed by android and was therefore counted as a second tab during the next opening.

Next, I use it like that :
For each request I check if the user is online, if not I switch to offline mode:

```
private async disableNetWorkIfOffline() {
    if (!this.networkService.isOnline()) {
        await this.afs.firestore.disableNetwork();
    } else {
        await this.afs.firestore.enableNetwork();
    }
}
```

- networkservice is one of my services
- I thought I understood from the documentation that this was done automatically, but for some reason it's not my case, so I do it manually